# Reference for "taking adjuncts preserves Kan extensions"

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, 2-categories, kan-extension

I'm using a result similar to the one below, and I would like to know if there is a reference that I can cite. It's easily proved, by "following your nose". The cell $G\phi.\eta_A$ is often called the "adjunct" of $\phi$, hence the title.

Let $F \dashv G\colon \mathcal D \to \mathcal C$ be a strict 2-adjunction, with 2-natural unit transformation $\eta\colon \text{id}_{\mathcal C} \Rightarrow GF$. Let $j\colon A \to B$ be in $\mathcal C$, and $d\colon FA \to M$ and $l\colon FB \to M$ be in $\mathcal D$.

If $\phi\colon d \Rightarrow l.Fj$ defines $l$ as the left Kan extension of $d$ along $Fj$ then $G\phi.\eta_A$ defines $Gl.\eta_B$ as the left Kan extension of $Gd.\eta_A$ along $j$.

Comment: Adjoints can be defined as a universal Kan extension. Is this fact not an instance of a general pasting law for Kan extensions?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Tim! I don't see how the pasting law can be used here: the Kan extension $l$ that we start with lives inside the 2-category $\mathcal D$ but the 2-adjunction is between $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$, if you see what I mean? To me this fact is simply "taking adjuncts of cells preserves the unique factorisations that define a Kan extension".

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread. I wish I knew a reference -- but if I were looking for such a reference I might ask you actually :)

Comment: As an example, applying the result to the tensor-hom 2-adjunction $X \times - \dashv [X, -]$ for the 2-category of categories, you get that a left Kan extension $l\colon X \times A \to M$ along $X \times j$ induces a left Kan extension $A \to [X, M]$, along $j$. You'd think that might have been useful before... I need a double-categorical variation and I was hoping to be able to point to this 2-categorical variant somewhere.

Comment: And it works for pointwise Kan extensions as well, as long as $F$ preserves comma objects. No problem Tim, nice to see a comment! :)